# Google Sheets API call getting 403 errors?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-api, squarespace

Working on a simple Sheets call to pull some data to our Squarespace website to update some displays.
The call was working on a test account, but once I moved a Sheets doc in our Google Workspace tenant everything started failing.

We're using a new API that was created exactly the same as the test, and a spreadsheet formatted & shared out the same. The only differences are sheet names, that it's in a Google Workspace tenant (that I directly manage), and we have an extension in Sheets pulling some data in from Squarespace.

The code we're using to pull call is:

```
<script>
    ( ( ) => {
      const googleApiKey = 'KEY';
      const googleSheetId = 'SHEETID';
      const googleSheetName = 'SHEETNAME';
      const googleSheetRange = 'CELL';
      const googleSheetsApiUrl = 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets';
      const url = googleSheetsApiUrl +
        '/' +
        googleSheetId +
        '/values/' +
        googleSheetName +
        '!' +
        googleSheetRange;
      $.getJSON ( url, { key : googleApiKey }, function ( data ) {
        console.log(data.values [ 0 ]);
        $( '#raised' ).width ( data.values [ 0 ] );
        } );
      } ) ( );
  </script>
```

I have a friend looking into it now to assist, but we're both at a loss here!

I've created new keys, re-published the specific page in the doc, reformated everything, created new docs to test, tried reverting to the old doc, compared all API and spreadsheet settings to the one that worked, and my friend has even created their own instance of everything on their end and is getting the same errors.